# Can you make a universal app using both MainWindow.xib for the iPhone and Storyboard for the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xib, uistoryboard, universal

I made an iPhone app long ago and I'm now thinking of making it a universal app, but I was wondering if I could use Storyboards for making the iPad version, so for the iPhone it would load a MainWindow.xib and for the iPad it would load a MainStoryboard file. Is this possible?

Comment: I think, unless the app is very complex, you would be better off just making it all storyboard.  That way all the transitions would be the same, and your code would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: That's the thing, the app is quite complex, and I don't think I would do it all over again for the iPad if Storyboards wasn't available, but before I rush into anything I need to know if I'm able to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you actually have to make two separate storyboards (1 for iPhone and 1 for iPad).

In the iPhone storyboard, just drag your mainwindow.xib into the middle of the rootViewController and make sure it goes full-screen.

Then, you can do whatever you want with your iPad storyboard.

Make sure that your two storyboard files are linked correctly in your project summary though!

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a go and see what happens, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Gazzini is right and got his answer in first while I was doing research to confirm that this was true & relatively straightforward before I got to type in my own answer.  So +1 to him.

You don't need two separate storyboards though.  You just need one storyboard for one architecture and your XIB files for the architecture you already support.

Here is a screenshots that might help show you what I did in my own test project:

[image: Yes It Is Possible]

Simply edit the plist of your application to use a "nib" file for the specific architecture you already have XIB files for, and then specify storyboards for the new architecture.

Comment: Thank you very for your answer too, but doing some research I found that in order to submit an app to the App Store, in my info.plist I can only set either NSMainNIBFile or UIMainStoryboardFile. I found this in the Information Property List Key Reference Guide where it says "NSMainNIBFile: This key is mutually exclusive with the 'UIMainStoryboardFile' (page 77) key. You should include one of the
keys in your Info.plist file but not both."

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler for you to use a storyboard on iPad and nibs on iPhone if you *don't* set Main Interface (`NSMainNibFile` in Info.plist) or a Main Storyboard (`NSMainStoryboardFile` in Info.plist).

Instead, move your app delegate out of `MainWindow.xib` and let `UIApplicationMain` instantiate it by passing its class name as the fourth argument to `UIApplicationMain` in `main`.  Make the app delegate the File's Owner of `MainWindow.xib`.

In your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, you can inspect the interface idiom.

If the interface idiom is iPhone, load `MainWindow` using `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`.

If the interface idiom is iPad, create your window, load `MainStoryboard` using `+[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:]`, instantiate its initial view controller with `-[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController]`, and set that view controller as your window's root view controller.